# Generate random value from list of numbers

Tags: ruby

How I can generate list of random values in Ruby from a list of numbers?

```
[100, 643, 826, 804, 372, 076, 156, 152, 036, 248]
```

How I can pick one random number from the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Array#sample`:

```
[100, 643, 826, 804, 372, 076, 156, 152, 036, 248].sample
```

Available in Ruby *1.9.1+*. In an earlier version of Ruby, you could

```
require 'backports/1.9.1/array/sample'
```

Comment: Are you sure it was 1.9.1 and not 1.9.0 that introduced `#sample`?